# Can I change the dimensions of a dialog box in the open: event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I already created a dialog box like this:

```
this.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 875,
            buttons: {
               ....<code here>
            },
            open: function (event, ui) {
                if ($(this).data('action') != "Editing HTML") {
```

is there some way that I could change the height and width inside the "open" to be:

```
    width: $(window).width() - 20,
    height: $(window).height() - 20,
```

If the above condition that checks "action" is met?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

You can change any/most of the dialog box paramters at after initializing by:

```
open: function (event, ui) {   //your dialog's open callback
    $('your_selecter').dialog('option','key','value');  //key can be width or height, value can be 20 or 40
    // And then rest of your code
}
```

check [dialog-options](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#options) for more info:

Comment: But can I change inside the "open:" event also ?

Comment: Yes by calling these inside your dialog's open callback! I have updated the answer, the open part your dialog.

Comment: Thanks - In this case would 'your_selector' be equal to the "this" as I want to change width/height of the dialog box.

Comment: yes in your case, it can be `this.dialog('option','key','value');`

Comment: Sorry to ask so much but is this.dialog the same as $(this).dialog ?

Comment: by default (unless not modified), this in jquery returns the actual `Dom` object, so `this.dialog` calling won't be possible, it would be better using `$(this).dialog` as it will return a jquery instance on `this`. So final answer is, `this` is a raw javascript dom instance, and $(this) is a jquery enabled in addition to raw javascript instance.